# How is state being used in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to look at a cover-tracker project I found on GitHub to understand how react can be used in useful applications. This is the following code I found in the beginning of the project, can someone please explain what it means please? I apologize if its a vague question.

For context the app lists all the countries and their current covid cases with an option to search a particular country

```
const GlobalList = () => {
  const state = useContext(AppContext);
  const { summaryData } = state;
  const [countriesSwitch, setCountriesSwitch] = useState("a");

  const countries = summaryData.Countries;



const RenderedCountries = () => {
    switch (countriesSwitch) {
      case "ascendingConfirmedCases":
        return countries
          .sort((a, b) => (a.TotalConfirmed < b.TotalConfirmed ? 1 : -1))
          .map((i, k) => {
            return (
              <Grid.Column key={k}>
                <CounrtyItem
                  country={correctedNames(i.Country)}
                  countryCode={i.CountryCode.toLowerCase()}
                  totalConfirmed={addComma(i.TotalConfirmed)}
                  totalRecovered={addComma(i.TotalRecovered)}
                  totalDeaths={addComma(i.TotalDeaths)}
                />
              </Grid.Column>
```

Comment: A tutorial (or several) might make more sense. Pick one off the things you're not understanding, find its docs and tutorials, write a small example. Lather rinse repeat--there's not too much code here.

Comment: Pick ReactJS tutorial or to understand this concept only you can see useEffect, useState in hooks,  array map function in React, using state and props in ReactJs. You can easily understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const state = useContext(AppContext);
```

#### Explanation :

In the first line here a hook named useContext is used . useContext hook is used to get the Context Value from the nearest value up the component tree. So somewhere in the parent components there is a context named `AppContext` which was passed down to the childs and our current component is one of the childrens.

-------------O-----------------

```
const { summaryData } = state;
```

#### Explanation

In thiis line  we are using es6 ```spread operator```` to extract the value of susmmaryData from the state variable.

---------------O-----------------

```
const [countriesSwitch, setCountriesSwitch] = useState("a");
```

#### Explanation

In this line we are maintaining a state variable to switch the countries state using `useState` hook . This hook is used to maintain local state in react components.

---------------O-----------------

```
  const countries = summaryData.Countries;
```

this is standard javascript. nothing to explain

---------------O-----------------

```
switch (countriesSwitch) {
      case "ascendingConfirmedCases":
        return countries
          .sort((a, b) => (a.TotalConfirmed < b.TotalConfirmed ? 1 : -1))
          .map((i, k) => {
            return (
              <Grid.Column key={k}>
                <CounrtyItem
                  country={correctedNames(i.Country)}
                  countryCode={i.CountryCode.toLowerCase()}
                  totalConfirmed={addComma(i.TotalConfirmed)}
                  totalRecovered={addComma(i.TotalRecovered)}
                  totalDeaths={addComma(i.TotalDeaths)}
                />
              </Grid.Column>
```

#### Explanation

Here in this switch statement we are rendering the component based on the value of `countriesSwitch` which is maintained in the local state as we mentioned before.